# How to center-align content within an iFrame who's size is dependent on different mobile-screen sizes?

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, transform

I am trying to display some content through an iframe.
1.The iframe window's height and width will be dependent on the height/width of a mobile screen and will thus vary based on the device screen size.
2.The content, which is designed within a  of width and height of 800px and 600px.
3.Based on the screen-size, the content will be scaled using 'transform:scale(x)'
The content will only be scaled down, no upscaling will happen.

Now, the I've managed to centre-align the content(#container) using some css-code

```css
#container{
 position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
margin:auto;
width:800px;
height:600px;
}
```

The above CSS is being applied to the container that I am trying to display in the iframe.

The iFrame size is dependent on the window.innerHeight

```
    var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe');
        iframe.height = window.innerHeight;
        iframe.width = window.innerWidth;
```

I am also applying full-screen to the iframe.

```
 iframe.requestFullscreen();
```

The container also gets scaled down, incase the device-height ( in landscape mode)

so a transform scale is applied to the container based on this.

Incase the screen-height is 300px,

```
#container{
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
margin:auto;
width:800px;
height:600px;

transform:scale(0.5);
}
```

This works fine for mobile screens which have a Width greater than 800px, in cases where the width is less than 800px, the content stops centre-aligning with respect to the screen-width.

NOTE: 
Content that I refer to is an interactive div, a mini-game of sorts which uses various positioned elements. Let us assume that this can't be modified and only the 800 x 600 div needs to be centre aligned.

Is there any solution to this? 
I can elaborate more if required.

I would like the content to centre align, even when the screen-width is less than 800px, when being shown through an iframe

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="parent">
    <iframe src="#"></iframe>
</div>
```

Maybe this:

```
.parent {
  display: block; //if it's for some reason something else
  text-align: center;
}
iframe {
 display: inline;
}
```

Comment: It didn't work, but Also the container will be scaled using 'transform:scale()' so it won't be 800/600, I've noticed that it's assuming that the original width of the container is being taken into account when the alignment starts to break but I can't find a solution.